# Xcode 6 Beta 3 unusable. Corrupted project?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, corrupt

Pretty much every time I try to type something in a particular project in Xcode6 beta3 I get the spinning wheel of death. Lasts for 10-20 seconds, at which point I can type a few more characters before it locks up again. This type of throttling makes it pretty hard to code. It also takes 1-2 minutes to build and run a simple project.

Any suggestions on what I can do? Tried restarting Xcode, restarting computer, etc.

I tried creating a new project, and the freezing doesn't seem to happen there. What can I do to fix the bad project?

EDIT: This is killing me! Stuff I've tried:

Deleting xcuserdata

Deleting the Build folder

Turning off indexing as recommended [here](http://birdchan.com/home/2013/03/21/xcode-keeps-freezing/)

Deleting the DerivedData folder

Answer (score 3):

If it's a single project that's causing this trouble, try deleting a folder called xcuserdata inside your project (right click your xcproj file, then select "show package contents"). When you re-open your project the problem should have cleared up.

Here' same link with more details: http://pinkstone.co.uk/xcode-crashes-every-time-you-open-it-and-how-to-fix-it/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't fix my issue. It doesn't crash completely. It just hangs for 20-30 seconds when I try to write code.